# cbind returns index of factor vector

Tags: r

I'm trying to concatenate 2 vectors, a vector of factors and a vector of character with the following code:

```
results2 <- cbind(customer, result)
```

The problem is that the vector customers is being concatenated with the row numbers, not the actual value of the customer factor.

It should return this

```
customer result
10         a
22         b
25         a
```

But instead it's returning this:

```
customer result
1         a
2         b
3         a
```

Comment: Try `cbind(as.character(customers), results)`

Comment: Have a look at the **Value** section of `?cbind` (or `?rbind`): "The type of a matrix result determined from the highest type of any of the inputs in the hierarchy raw < logical < integer < double < complex < character < list". Also check `f1 <- factor(0:1); f2 <- factor(c("0", "1")); typeof(f1); typeof(f2)`. See `?factor`: "an object of class "factor" which has a set of integer codes the length of x with a "levels" attribute of mode character"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That is because by using `cbind` you convert your data to a `matrix` object and matrices in R can only contain one type of objects / class. So your `factor` variable `customer` is converted and only the factor levels remain (the 1, 2, 3 are not row names but the "numbering" of factor levels). If you just want to create a data.frame you could use

```
data.frame(customers, results)
```

instead, bc data.frames allow different types of variables combined in one data.frame.